# JsonField in DRF

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like below that include **JsonField**:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_field=15)
    data = models.JSONField()
```

the ***data*** field structure is like below:

```
[
   {
    "age":"15",
    "color":white,
    ...
   },
   {
    ...
    ...
   }
]
```

And my goal is to show this model in **DRF** like below:

```
[
   {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Bell",
       "data": [
                  {
                      "age":"15",
                      "color":"white",
                      ...
                  },
                  {
                       ...,
                       ...
                   }
               ]
   }
]
```

But when i use JsonFeild in my model my data generated liKe:

```
[
   {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Bell",
       "data": "[{\"age\":\"15\",\"color\":\"white\",...},{\...,|... }]"
   }
]
```

It's converted to string and have \ in characters.

My serializer:

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Animal
    fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [JSONField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield) with an encoder attribute?

Comment: Can you add the content of the `views.py` file into the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem:

I converted my data to json with `json.dumps()` and assigned the json data to JsonField , the reason of `"[{\"..\"}]"` was that, i just need to assign my dictionary to JsonField.

Answer (score 0):

To tell DRF explicitly how to handle the `data` field you can assign `ListField` serializer (since as I can see its first level is a list) to it like so:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializer.ListField()
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = "__all__"
```

Optionally, you can pass the `child` argument into the `ListField` which is also a serializer, but for the list items so they'll be validated, too.

Or you can use JSONField if it works for you.

Documentation:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield